# WPF WebBrowser and special characters like german "umlaute"

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, diacritics, mhtml

I use the WPF WebBrowser Control in my app. I have a file (mht) which contains german umlaute (ä ö ü). Now, I load this this file with .Navigate(path) but the Problem is, that this charactes are not shown correct. How can I solve this?

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it with the following:

```
    static void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
        var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
        if(webBrowser == null) {
            return;
        }
        var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document;           

        doc.charset = "utf-8";
        webBrowser.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Where is IHTMLDocument2?

Comment: @AlbertoTorre It's an internal interface located here: `MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLDocument2`. I'm not sure how to access this interface without compilation errors :)

Answer (score 8):

This is very quirky.

1. My solution was to put an explicit meta tag in my HTML file - "My Page.html"

   ```
   <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'>
   ```
2. Then using the standard Web Browser .NET control I then created a URI object first.

   ```
   webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("My Page.html");
   ```
3. Then draw the page using the refresh method.

   ```
   webBrowser1.Refresh();
   ```

Note if you use the Navigate method directly it fails to pick up the utf-8 directive, but the URI and refresh approach does.

Quirky, but it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO Gavin. Instead of trying to have a nice render for `<` & `>` you should add 4 spaces to highlight the code or put them between `.

Comment: Item 2. solves my issue (being having special chars in the url path, my url is a local file), was passing a string to Navigate, passing a url instead works.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with this problem this morning and it annoyed me a lot until I found this solution:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Content_Of_HTML_File_In_String)));
webBrowser.NavigateToStream(stream);
```

Compared to the solution above, you wont expect any "COMException" or something of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control uses Internet Explorer internally, whichever version you have on your local PC.  If you can fix the problem in IE, it should be fixed in the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Ok. I have seen, that I can change the Encoding in IE. When I load my file and change the Encoding to UTF-8, all is showing perfect. But I cannot find the place, where I can change the Encoding in the WebBrowser control. Can you help me about that?

Comment: In your page you can try setting encoding (charset) in this format: `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-JP">`